# Modern implementation of Spring Remoting or EJB3

Tags: java

Im working on a "what is possible with the latest and greatest" prototype.  One major issue that has been a big thorn in the side of myself and my AS/400 admin is when the existing system spins up, there are 35 individual applications, that each connect to 8 databases, and run a connection pool of 5 connections per.  for you math wizards out there, thats 1400 individual database connections to the server on startup and over the course of a typical day maybe 40 are ever used.

What I would like to do in this prototype is move all database functions to a central library (api).  From that point, I would like to deploy this API individually and have the 35 applications simply open service classes remotely and pass objects back and forth.  end result being the applications no longer have to create database connections, they simply call remote methods and we can tune the central api accordingly to handle the load.

Back in the day, EJB3 would have been the way to go.  the integration with security policies is nice, but i always had performance issues with it.  Spring remoting running hessian looks promising, seeing im using spring everywhere else.  but it has been YEARS since i have had to do anything like this so i was wondering what you guys suggest to use to accomplish this.

thanks

Comment: AS/400 - I'm not familiar with that, so a few Q's. 1.) How are the apps deployed? 2.) What JVM/App Server/Web Server are the apps running on?

Comment: the new server will be jboss 7.1 they are deployed as war files.  we are running jvm 6 at the moment, but switching to 7 isn't out of the question.  for my purposes, its easiest to think of the 400 as a huge DB2 server

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for answering the Q's!

Jboss 7.1 should be able to supply a shared connection pool for all of your applications.  Checkout the `JBOSS_DIST/docs/examples/jca` folder for example datasource configurations.

Also see [Apache's Database Connection Pooling](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/configuration.html) library. You can swap that in if Jboss's native solution doesn't cut it.

Also, ask on JBoss.org - they're a pretty proactive bunch.